# Android Notifications - on Flashlight app

Tags: android, notifications, android-camera, resume, flashlight

I have a problem with a simple flashlight application.
I have integrate a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK fuction now the user can press home or power button when the app with led/on running. So for make more intuitive I want to integrate a notifications system on android bar and when the user click on Notification can return to the activity that is running, but there is a problem when click on notification the intent go to a new activity and try to get the camera parameters. Result the app crash and after restart.

My notification code:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    wakeLock.acquire();

    if (isFlashlightOn) {
        nmgr =      (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti = new Notification(R.drawable.small_ico,"LED/ON", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        PendingIntent PIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);
        noti.setLatestEventInfo(this, "FLASHLIGHT", "LED / ON", pIntent);
        nmgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,noti);

    } else {
        nmgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti = new Notification(R.drawable.small_ico,"LED/OFF", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        PendingIntent PIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);
        noti.setLatestEventInfo(this, "FLASHLIGHT", "LED / OFF", pIntent);
        nmgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,noti);
    }
    int mod=myAudioManager.getRingerMode();

}
```

This is the code about Pause, Resume ecc.

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    int mod=myAudioManager.getRingerMode();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
  }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    int mod=myAudioManager.getRingerMode();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
      }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    if (isFlashlightOn) {
    } else {
      setFlashlightOn();
    }
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}
```

My questions is how can that when click to the notification resume the activity that is running ?

Error from crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.flashlight, PID: 16164
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flashlight/com.flashlight.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:469)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:442)
at com.flashlight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:292)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5305)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it's strange because the problem only occurs when starting for the first time the application was just installed, after closing and reopening it works perfectly.

it seems like if the intent of notifications on click was going on other application process and crash because the camera parameters have already been taken.

maybe there is a problem with the shortcut ?

Help me please
Thank you all

Comment: include stacktrace from crash. Also you do not call `finish()` in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Thanks ... I deleted it does not work anyway

Comment: include stacktrace from crash

Comment: ok report from crash added

Comment: it's strange because the problem only occurs when starting for the first time the application was just installed, after closing and reopening it works perfectly.

it seems like if the intent of notifications on click was going on other application process and crash because the camera parameters have already been taken.

maybe there is a problem with the shortcut ?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`. in `onCreate` which you stripped from your question code